# How to deepmerge dicts/list for a json in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

I'm trying to deepmerge lists to get a specific json.

what I want to achieve is this format (the order of the elements is irelevant):

```
{
 "report": {
    "context": [{
            "report_id": [
                "Report ID 30"
            ],
            "status": [
                "Status 7"
            ],
            "fallzahl": [
                "Fallzahl 52"
            ],
            "izahl": [
                "IZahl 20"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "körpergewicht": [{
            "any_event_en": [{
                    "gewicht": [{
                            "|magnitude": 185.44,
                            "|unit": "kg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "kommentar": [
                        "Kommentar 94"
                    ],
                    "bekleidung": [{
                            "|code": "at0011"
                        }
                    ]
                   
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}
I try to deepmerge dicts and lists to achieve this specific format. My baseline are some dicts:

{'körpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'gewicht': [{'|magnitude': '100', '|unit': 'kg'}]}]}]}

{'körpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'bekleidung': [{'|code': 'at0013'}]}]}]}

{'körpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'kommentar': ['none']}]}]}

{'context': [{'status': ['fatty']}]}

{'context': [{'fallzahl': ['123']}]}

{'context': [{'report_id': ['123']}]}

{'context': [{'izahl': ['123']}]}

what I tried to do is following I have a dict called tmp_dict in that I hold a baseline dict as I loop through. The so called collect_dict is the dict in that I try to merge my baseline dicts. element holds my current baseline dict.

```
if (index == (len(element)-1)): #when the baseline dict is traversed completely
   if tmp_dict:
      first_key_of_tmp_dict=list(tmp_dict.keys())[0]
      if not (first_key_of_tmp_dict in collect_dict):
         collect_dict.update(tmp_dict)
      else:
         merge(tmp_dict,collect_dict)
   else:
      collect_dict.update(tmp_dict)
```

and I also wrote a merge method:

```
    def merge(tmp_dict,collect_dict):
        first_common_key_of_dicts=list(tmp_dict.keys())[0]
        second_depth_key_of_tmp_dict=list(tmp_dict[first_common_key_of_dicts][0].keys())[0]
        second_depth_tmp_dict=tmp_dict[first_common_key_of_dicts][0]
        second_depth_key_of_coll_dict=collect_dict[first_common_key_of_dicts][0]
        if not second_depth_key_of_tmp_dict in second_depth_key_of_coll_dict:
            collect_dict.update(second_depth_tmp_dict)
        else:
            merge(second_depth_tmp_dict,second_depth_key_of_coll_dict)
```

what I'm coming up with goes in the right direction but is far from beeing my desired output:

```
{"report": {
                "k\u00f6rpergewicht": [{
                        "any_event_en": [{
                                "kommentar": ["none"]
                            }
                        ],
                        "bekleidung": [{
                                "|code": "at0013"
                            }
                        ],
                        "gewicht": [{
                                "|magnitude": "100",
                                "|unit": "kg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "context": [{
                        "fallzahl": ["234"]
                    }
                ],
                "report_id": ["234"],
                "status": ["s"],
                "izahl": ["234"]
            }
}
```

With another set of inputs:

```
{'atemfrequenz': {'context': [{'status': [{'|code': 'at0012'}]}]}},
{'atemfrequenz': {'context': [{'kategorie': ['Kategorie']}]}},
{'atemfrequenz': {'atemfrequenz': [{'messwert': [{'|magnitude': '123', '|unit': 'min'}]}]}}
```

I would like to achieve the following output:

```
"atemfrequenz": {
    "context": [
      {
        "status": [
          {
            "|code": "at0012"
          }
        ],
        "kategorie": [
          "Kategorie"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "atemfrequenz": [
      {
        "messwert": [
          {
            "|magnitude": 123,
            "|unit": "/min"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should get the correct answer. I removed the special character (ö) to prevent errors.

```
dd = [
{'korpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'gewicht': [{'|magnitude': '100', '|unit': 'kg'}]}]}] },
{'korpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'bekleidung': [{'|code': 'at0013'}]}]}]},
{'korpergewicht': [{'any_event_en': [{'kommentar': ['none']}]}]},
{'context': [{'status': ['fatty']}]},
{'context': [{'fallzahl': ['123']}]},
{'context': [{'report_id': ['123']}]},
{'context': [{'izahl': ['123']}]}
]


def merge(d):
   if (type(d) != type([])): return d
   if (type(list(d[0].values())[0])) == type(""): return d
   keys = list(set(list(k.keys())[0] for k in d))
   lst = [{k:[]} for k in keys]
   for e in lst:
       for k in d:
           if (list(e.keys())[0] == list(k.keys())[0]):
               e[list(e.keys())[0]] += k[list(k.keys())[0]]
   for e in lst:
       if (type(e[list(e.keys())[0]][0]) == type({})):
           e[list(e.keys())[0]] = merge(e[list(e.keys())[0]]) 
       for i in lst[1:]: lst[0].update(i)
   lst2 = []  # return list of single dictionary
   lst2.append(lst[0])
   return lst2

dx = merge(dd)
dx = {'report': dx[0]} # no list at lowest level
print(dx)
```

Output (formatted)

```
{'report': {
     'korpergewicht': [{
          'any_event_en': [{
                'kommentar': ['none'], 
                'bekleidung': [{'|code': 'at0013'}], 
                'gewicht': [{'|magnitude': '100', '|unit': 'kg'}]}]}], 
      'context': [{
          'report_id': ['123'], 
          'izahl': ['123'], 
          'fallzahl': ['123'], 
          'status': ['fatty']}]}}
```

Concerning the second data set provided, the data needs to structured to match the previous data set.

This data set works correctly:

```
dd = [
{'atemfrequenz': [{'context': [{'status': [{'|code': 'at0012'}]}]}]}, 
{'atemfrequenz': [{'context': [{'kategorie': ['Kategorie']}]}]}, 
{'atemfrequenz': [{'atemfrequenz': [{'messwert': [{'|magnitude': '123', '|unit': 'min'}]}]}]} 
]
```

Output (formatted)

```
{'report': {
    'atemfrequenz': [{
         'atemfrequenz': [{
              'messwert': [{'|magnitude': '123', '|unit': 'min'}]}], 
    'context': [{
         'kategorie': ['Kategorie'], 
         'status': [{'|code': 'at0012'}]}]}]}}
```

Comment: in your answer the lines are dicts but they are supposed to be one single dict than each one as a dict lists like this: "körpergewicht": [{ "any_event_en": [{ "gewicht": [{ "|magnitude": 185.44, "|unit": "kg" } ], "kommentar": [ "Kommentar 94" ], "bekleidung": [{ "|code": "at0011" } ]

Comment: your code worked fine for me untill I used these inputs:'[{'atemfrequenz': {'context': [{'status': [{'|code': 'at0012'}]}]}}, {'atemfrequenz': {'context': [{'kategorie': ['Kategorie']}]}}, {'atemfrequenz': {'atemfrequenz': [{'messwert': [{'|magnitude': '123', '|unit': 'min'}]}]}}]', now I get this after the merge [{'atemfrequenz': ['context', 'context', 'atemfrequenz']}]

Comment: If you make a small change to the data structure, it processes correctly.

Comment: I can't figure out where

Comment: For me your last changes don't work correctly, I updated my question, for a better overview.